# Disarium Dilemma

Tags: code-golf, sequence

### Disarium Dilemma

A Disarium is defined as a number whose:

> sum of its digits powered with their respective position is equal to the original number

---

**Your Task**:

You have a strange obsession with numbers classified as being a disarium.  The need to follow the ways of disarium is so great in you that you **refuse** to read any non-disarium numbered pages in any given book.  You have two **BIG** problems:

1. Your professor just assigned you to read your textbook from page `n` to page `m`
2. You hit your head really hard last week and can't seem to remember how to programmatically determine if a number is considered to be a disarium.

Time is of the essence so the code to determine the pages you will need to read needs to be as short as possible.

You need to identify all of the disarium within an inclusive range of `n` through `m`.

**Examples of a disarium**:

> 89 = 8<sup>1</sup> + 9<sup>2</sup>
>
> 135 = 1<sup>1</sup> + 3<sup>2</sup> + 5<sup>3</sup>
>
> 518 = 5<sup>1</sup> + 1<sup>2</sup> + 8<sup>3</sup>

This is code-golf, so the least number of bytes wins!

Here is the full sequence of [A032799](https://oeis.org/A032799).

Comment: @Fatalize The range is inclusive, I will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: Are there any guaranteed bounds on `n` and `m`? There’s a very big disarium (12157692622039623539), should answers be able to identify it?

Comment: @Lynn Given that there are already a number of solutions, I would say there should be no bounds on the range.

Comment: @Lynn. There is no disarium >22 digits, so in a way the range is already bounded.

Comment: [OEIS link to disarium numbers](https://oeis.org/A032799), for anyone interested.

Comment: Are we guaranteed that `a` and `b` are both larger than 0?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Why would that be the case? Can you link to a proof (if there is one), I'm genuinely interested. Thanks!

Comment: @FlipTack If `n` and `m` are negative, it shouldn't return any values as is the nature of the sequence.

Comment: @MistahFiggins Please go to the OEIS link at the bottom of the question.  You will find a proof that shows the Disarium sequence is indeed finite.

Answer (score 11):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), <s>40</s> 39 bytes

```
{grep {$_==sum .comb Z**1..*},$^a..$^b}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#y61UUEtTsP1fnV6UWqBQXVyaq6GXnJ@bpBClpWWop6elmVqoEl@ro6ASl6inpxKXVPu/OLFSIU3B0MBAR8HMwMD6PwA)

#### How it works

```
{                                     }  # A lambda.
                              $^a..$^b   # Range between the two lambda arguments.
 grep {                     },           # Return numbers from that range which satisfy:
               .comb Z  1..*             #  Digits zipped with the sequence 1,2,3,...,
                      **                 #  with exponentiation operator applied to each pair,
           sum                           #  and those exponents summed,
       $_==                              #  equals the number.
```

Answer (score 8):

## Python2, <s>98</s> <s>89</s> <s>88</s> 84 bytes

```
lambda n,m:[x for x in range(n,m+1)if sum(int(m)**-~p for p,m in enumerate(`x`))==x]
```

<s>Horrible. Will get shorter.</s> Starting to look better

Here's my recursive attempt (86 bytes):

```
f=lambda n,m:[]if n>m else[n]*(sum(int(m)**-~p for p,m in enumerate(`n`))==n)+f(n+1,m)
```

Thanks to [@Rod](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47120/rod) for saving 4 bytes! `range` to `enumerate` and so on.

Comment: switching to `enumerate`, you can use `int(n)` instead `int(\`x\`[p])`

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>105</s> <s>91</s> <s>89</s> <s>88</s> <s>83</s> <s>79</s> <s>82</s> 81 bytes

*Thanks to Arnauld for saving 20B, and ETHProductions for saving 6B!*

```
a=>b=>[...Array(b).keys()].filter(c=>c>=a&([...c+''].map(d=>c-=d**++e,e=0),!c))
```

### Usage

Assign the function to a variable, and give it the minimum and the maximum as arguments. Example:

```
f=a=>b=>[...Array(b).keys()].filter(c=>c>=a&([...c+''].map(d=>c-=d**++e,e=0),!c))
f(0)(90)
```

#### Output

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 89]
```

### Further golfing

This seems pretty well-golfed, but there's always room for improvement... I think.

Comment: Yeah, that's actually quite a bit shorter. Thanks!

Comment: You can change `d**(e+1)` to `d**-~e` to save two bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, added it. Only 2 more bytes before we've beaten Python...

Comment: You can use `&` instead of `&&`. One more byte to go...

Comment: I just changed that in my local copy... Guess you were faster.

Comment: `[...c+''].reduce((p,c,e)=>p+c**-~e,0)` should save a few more bytes.

Comment: Oh no :( Looks like JS holds the title (for the moment).

Comment: Indeed, but I just added another improvement, which uses `'' == 0`.

Comment: Seems like the current version is 88 bytes, rather than 86. (The `reduce` version is 83, I think.)

Comment: Oops, you're right. I'll use the `reduce` version.

Comment: You can use `.map` to save a few more bytes: `c=>c>a&([...c+''].map(d=>c-=d**++e,e=0),!c)`

Comment: The post states that it's in _inclusive_ range, so you need to include both endpoints.

Comment: Hmm, the rules must have been updated since I posted my answer. I included the lower endpoint at the cost of 3 bytes.

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3, 100 bytes

```python
lambda n,m:{*range(10),89,135,175,518,598,1306,1676,2427,2646798,0xa8b8cd06890f2773}&{*range(n,m+1)}
```

Not the shortest approach, but a pretty cute one. There are finitely many disariums; see the OEIS page for a nice proof. These are all of them.

Comment: This is use of hard-coding which is a loophole http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1063/55243 I would recommended you change your answer to fit with the standard rules

Comment: I don't think this violates the hard-coding rule, as the program still "does work" and the *output* is not hard-coded.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to  [Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47066/emigna)

```
ŸvygLySmOyQ—
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@390R1lluk9lcK5/ZeCjhin//xtwGRoAAQA)

```
Ÿ            # push [a .. b]
 vy          # for each
   gL        # push [1 .. num digits]
     yS      # push [individual digits]
       m     # push [list of digits to the power of [1..num digits] ]
        O    # sum
         yQ— # print this value if equal
```

Comment: `ŸvygLySmOyQ—` should work for 12 bytes.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (Firefox 52+), 68 bytes

```
f=(n,m)=>(e=0,[for(d of t=n+'')t-=d**++e],t||alert(n),n-m&&f(n+1,m))
```

Recursive function that outputs via `alert`. Works in the Developer Edition of Firefox, which you can download on [this page](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/desktop/?v=a). Previous versions of Firefox don't support the `**` operator, and no other browser supports `[for(a of b)c]` syntax.

#### Test snippet

This uses `.map` instead of an array comprehension, and `Math.pow` instead of `**`, so it should work in all browsers that support ES6.

```js
f=(n,m)=>(e=0,[...t=n+''].map(d=>t-=Math.pow(d,++e)),t||alert(n),n-m&&f(n+1,m))

f(0,100)
```

Answer (score 6):

## Perl, 43 bytes

```
map{say if$_==eval s/./+$&**$+[0]/gr}<>..<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#@5@bWFBdnFipkJmmEm9rm1qWmKNQrK@nr62ipqWloh1tEKufXlRrY6enZ2P3/78hl6GBgcF/XV9TPQNDAwA)

Regex is really powerful, you guys.

### Explanation

The first thing the code does is read two integers as input via `<>`, and creates a range from the first to the second with `..`.  It then uses the standard `map` function to iterate through this range, and applies the following code to each value: `say if$_==eval s/./+$&**$+[0]/gr`.  This looks like gibberish, and it kind of is, but here's what's really happening.

`map` implicitly stores its current value in the variable `$_`.  Many perl functions and operations use this value when none is given.  This includes regular expressions, such as the `s///` substitution operator.

There are four parts to a substitution regex:

1. String to be manipulated.  Ordinarily, the operator `=~` is used to apply a regex to a string, but if this operator is absent, then the regex is applied to the implicit variable `$_`, which contains our current number via the `map` function.
2. String to search for.  In this case, we're searching for any single non-newline character, denoted by the wildcard `.`.  In effect, we're capturing each individual digit.
3. String to replace with.  We're substituting a plus sign `+` followed by a mathematical expression, mixed in with some magical Perl variables that make everything significantly easier.

The special scalar variable `$&` always contains the entirety of the last successful regex capture, which in this case is a single digit.  The special array variable `@+` always contains a list of *postmatch offsets* for the last successful match, i.e. the index of the text *after* the match.  `$+[0]` is the index in `$_` of the text immediately following `$&`.  In the case of `135`, we capture the digit `1`, and the index in `135` of the text immediately afterwards (namely, `35`) is 1, which is our exponent.  So, we want to raise `$&` (1) to the power of `$+[0]` (1) and get 1.  We want to raise 3 to the power of 2 and get 9.  We want to raise 5 to the power of 3 and get 125.

If the input was `135`, the resulting string is `+1**1+3**2+5**3`.

4. Regex-modifying flags.  Here we're using two regex flags -- `/g` and `/r`.  `/g` tells the interpreter to continue replacements after the first is found (otherwise we'd end up with `+1**135`). `/r` tells the interpreter *not to modify the original string*, and instead return what the string would be after the replacements.  This is important, because otherwise, it would overwrite `$_`, and we need it for comparison purposes.

Once the entire substitution is done, we get a mathematical expression, which is evaluated with the `eval` function.  `+1**1+3**2+5**3` is evaluated into `1 + 9 + 125 = 135`, which is compared to the original number `135`.  Since these two are equal, the code prints the number.

Comment: Beautiful solution. (Note that this won't work is the first input is 0, but I'm not sure it matters). A few bytes to golf: `map$_-eval s/./+$&**$+[0]/gr||say,<>..<>`

Comment: And `"@+"` is 1 byte shorter than `$+[0]` :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
D*J$S⁼
rÇÐf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@@i5eKlEvyocQ9X0eH2wxPS/v//b2Tw39DEAAA)

Got this down from 16 to 11, with some help from @miles!

Explanation:

```
rÇÐf    Main link, arguments are m and n
r       Generate a list from m to n
 Ç      Invoke the helper link
  Ðf    And filter out all that don't return 1 on that link

D*J$S⁼  Helper link, determines if item is Disarium
D       Break input (the current item of our list in Main) into digits (135 --> [1, 3, 5])
  J$    Create a range from 1 to x, where x is the number of digits             [1, 2, 3]
 *      Raise each digit to the power of their respective index 
    S⁼  And return a 1 if the sum of powers is equal to the helper-link's input
```

Comment: You can use `J` to get indices. A shorter way might be `D*J$S⁼` to combine your two links into one

Comment: Arrived at exactly that conclusion about 20 sec ago. Thnx!

Answer (score 4):

### R, 100 bytes

```
function(n,m,x=n:m)x[sapply(x,function(y)sum(as.integer(el(strsplit(c(y,""),"")))^(1:nchar(y)))==y)]
```

Unnamed function that takes `n` and `m`. As always in R, splitting integers into a numeric digit vector is tedious and eats up a lot of bytes. This makes the function relatively slow and only works for 32-bit integers.

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 23 bytes

```
q~),\>{_Ab_,,:).#:+=},p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@19Yp6kTY1cd75gUr6NjpamnbKVtW6tT8P@/hYGCqZEBAA)

**Explanation**

```
q~                      Get and eval all input
  ),\>                  Get the range between m and n, inclusive
      {                 For each number in the range...
       _Ab               Duplicate and get the list of digits
          _,,:)          Duplicate the list, take its length, make the range from 1 to length
               .#        Vectorize with exponentiation; computes first digit^1, second^2, etc
                 :+      Sum the results
                   =     Compare to the original number
                    },  Filter the range to only numbers for which the above block is true
                      p Print nicely
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 18 bytes

```
Ÿvy©SDgLsmO®Qi®}})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@390R1nloZXBLuk@xbn@h9YFZh5aV1ur@f@/AZehARAAAA)

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2.X, 92 bytes

```
lambda m,n:[k for k in range(m,n+1)if sum(int(j)**(i+1) for i,j in enumerate(list(`k`)))==k]
```

Comment: Useless whitespace after `(i+1)`, but this is not a problem, when you get rid of the parentheses by doing `-~i`.

Comment: That'd make my attempt exact same as yours!

Comment: Almost. You have `list('k')`, which I don't have. However, you can still remove the whitespace :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 84 bytes

A full program approach, currently the same length as the lambda solution.

```py
a,b=input()
while a<=b:
 t=p=0
 for x in`a`:p+=1;t+=int(x)**p
 if t==a:print a
 a+=1
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#DcpNCoAgEAbQ/ZziW/a3SEIoa@7SCElC1BBG3d7cPl6WznM89UlVTe8ejw2ysHeExMo9IVw3PsRzldVpy2ZObfmp@uqmUUIMJbI4vQtCCFJOzmawHew0/g)

Comment: Hmm. I thought about the almost exact answer, but discarded due to confusion with `input()`. Very nice! +1.

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, 15 bytes

```
òV f_¥Zì £XpYÄÃx
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.3&code=8lYgZl+lWuwgo1hwWcTDeA==&input=MCw2MDA=) This was a collaboration between @obarakon and myself.

#### How it works

```
òV f_¥Zì £XpYÄÃx   // Implicit: U, V = input integers
òV                 // Create the inclusive range [U...V].
   f_              // Filter to only the items Z where...
               x   //   the sum of
      Zì           //   the decimal digits of Z,
         £XpYÄÃ    //   where each is raised to the power of (index + 1),
     ¥             //   is equal to Z.
                   // Implicit: output result of last expression
```

In the latest version of Japt, `x` accepts a function as an argument, which allows us to golf another byte:

```
òV f_¥Zì x@XpYÄ
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=8lYgZl+lWuwgeEBYcFnE&input=MCw2MDA=)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
ŸʒDSāmOQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6I5Tk1yCjzTm@gf@/29oAARcBgA)

Answer (score 2):

### Clojure, 107 bytes

```
#(for[i(range %(inc %2)):when(=(int(apply +(map(fn[i v](Math/pow(-(int v)48)(inc i)))(range)(str i))))i)]i)
```

Implementing the equation is terribly long.

Comment: can save a couple of bytes by doing `(.pow(-(int v)48M)`

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 85 bytes

```
Input 
For(I,X,Y
If I<=9 or sum(I={89,135,175,518,598,1306,1676,2427,2646798,12157692622039623539
Disp I
End
```

Comment: I did not know hard-coding was permitted. :)

Comment: @AbelTom Well, it really helps that this series only has 20 terms. Also, converting number to string in TI-Basic takes lots of bytes. Only other solution would be to `int(log(` every number and then do the powers. Perhaps this is shorter, but I doubt it.

Comment: That input method is very clever but kind of sketchy. You need to be in `FUNC` mode and the window has to be set up to include your input point. Doesn't seem portable enough to me.

Comment: @JakobCornell By default the calc is in `FUNC` mode, although I do see what you're saying about the input resolution. But, this method is pretty common in golfing. You could always `Prompt X,Y` instead.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>92</s> <s>91</s> 88 bytes

3 bytes saved thanks @AlexHowansky

```php
for([,$n,$m]=$argv;$n<=$m;$s-$n++?:print"$s,")for($i=$s=0;_>$b=($n._)[$i++];)$s+=$b**$i;
```

takes input from command line arguments; prints a trailing comma. Run with `-r`.

Comment: Save three with `for([,$n,$m]=$argv;$n<=$m;`

Comment: Strange that print works there but echo doesn't. I guess because echo doesn't return anything -- not even null, oddly.

Comment: @AlexHowansky: It´s also strange that `"$n"[index]` and `"_$n"[index]` produce parse errors while `"89"[index]` and `$s="$n";$s[index]` are perfectly fine.

Comment: Hmm yes, that does seem odd at first, but after checking the docs, it appears they do explicitly say that the feature works only for string literals.

Comment: Heh heh well this works, but it probably doesn't save you any bytes: `("_$n")[index]`

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 61 bytes

```
n#m=[i|i<-[n..m],i==sum(zipWith(^)(read.pure<$>show i)[1..])]
```

Usage example `5 # 600` -> `[5,6,7,8,9,89,135,175,518,598]`.

Check each number `i` in the range `[n..m]`. The digits are extracted by turning `i` into a string (`show`) and making each char a one element string (`pure`) which is turned into an integer again (`read`). Zip those numbers element wise with `[1..]` via the function `^` and take the `sum`.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 59 bytes

```
Select[Range@##,Tr[(d=IntegerDigits@#)^Range@Length@d]==#&]&
```

Unnamed function taking two integer arguments and returning a list of integers. `(d=IntegerDigits@#)^Range@Length@d` produces the list of digits of a number to the appropriate powers; `Tr[...]==#` detects whether the sum of those digit-powers equals the original number.

Answer (score 2):

## **MATLAB, <s>88</s> 73 bytes**

```
@(n,m)find(arrayfun(@(n)n==sum((num2str(n)-48).^(1:log10(n)+1)),n:m))+n-1
```

Original answer:

```
function g(n,m);a=n:m;a(arrayfun(@(n)n==sum((num2str(n)-'0').^(1:floor(log10(n))+1)),a))
```

`num2str(n)-'0'` splits a `n` into a vector of its digits, and `1:floor(log10(n))+1` is a vector holding one to the number of digits in `n`. Thanks to  [log](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64590/log) for the golf down to an anonymous function, saving 15 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
òV fÈ¶ìxÈpYÄ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=8lYgZsi27HjIcFnE&input=MCw2MDA)

```
òV fÈ¶ìxÈpYÄ     :Implicit input of integers U & V
òV               :Range [U,V]
   f             :Filter by
    È            :Passing each through the following function
     ¶           :  Check for equality with
      ì          :  Convert to digit array
       x         :  Reduce by addition
        È        :  After passing each element at 0-based index Y through the following function
         p       :    Raise to the power of
          YÄ     :    Y+1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
⟦₂∋.i₁ᶠ^ᵐ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6OmpofbFjzc1Vn7cOuE/4/mLwMKPOro1st81NQIlIgDimr//x8dbWhqoKNgaAAEsbEA)

Generates each disarium through the output variable.

```
   .          The output variable is
  ∋           an element of
⟦₂            the inclusive range between the elements of the input.
      ᶠ       Find every
    i₁        pair of a digit and its 1-index in the output variable,
       ^ᵐ     and raise each digit to the power of its index.
         +    The sum is equal to the output variable.
```

Also worth mentioning here, rather than in a comment or its own submission, that steenbergh's Jelly solution can now be golfed down to `rD*J$S⁼ƲƇ`, but I might find this a bit more idiomatic:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
rD*J$SƊƑƇ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/IRctLJfhY17GJx9r///9vaGrw39AACAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), 82 bytes

```
a=[n...m]
d=\floor(\log a)
f(n,m)=a[a=\sum_{i=0}^d\mod(\floor(a/10^i),10)^{d-i+1}]
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9a2v2hbnq7)

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 100 bytes

```
for i in range(input(),input()+1):x=sum(int(`i`[n])**-~n for n in range(len(`i`)));print("",x)[x==i]
```

I haven't had a chance to run this yet (doing this on my phone).

Comment: This doesn't work. Incorrect syntax and when corrected, would print only boolean values. Starts from the exponent 0, which is also incorrect. Also, you don't need the square brackets inside `sum`.

Comment: This isn't checking for disarium numbers.

Comment: @hashcode55, fixed (?)

Comment: @TuukkaX, now it should work I think

Comment: I'm not on computer, but this should print a newline on each iteration, where `i` is a Disarium. I have no idea whether this is allowed, but I would say no, since the output gets very blank.

Comment: The submission should output the Disarium within an inclusive range of `n` through `m`, not produce new lines... How would you ever know which pages you needed to read??

Comment: @CraigR8806, it prints the number, `x`, if it's valid otherwise a newline. Is that not allowed?

Comment: @Dopapp sorry I misread the implementation.  I still think this would not be admissible as towards the higher end of the range there are large gaps between each Disarium.  You would have a large number of new lines separating your output if this were the case.

Comment: `(n+1)` could be `-~n`.

Comment: @TuukkaX, oh thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>82 76</s> 75 bytes

```hs
n!m=[x|x<-[n..m],x==x#(length.show)x]
0#i=0
n#i=(div n 10)#(i-1)+mod n 10^i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@nmGsbXVFTYaMbnaenlxurU2FrW6GskZOal16SoVeckV@uWRHLZaCcaWvAlQckNVIyyxTyFAwNNJU1MnUNNbVz81PA/LjM/7mJmXkKtgoFpSXBJUUKegog3QoqCgaKhuZm/wE) Usage: `5 ! 175`

This checks each number in the range `n` to `m` if its a disarium number and is hence quite slow for big `m`.

---

Faster version: (93 bytes)

```hs
n!m=[x|x<-[0..9]++[89,135,175,518,598,1306,1676,2427,2646798,12157692622039623539],x>=n,x<=m]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#FcwxDgIhEEDRq8wmdjsSGHYGJlm8hCWhsNMCNLpGCu@Oa/lf8Uebasr929djtsZomeccFZ1ndIGRXUTWuLcVdBIEaaGAJIuEP5PjIEpCZL0KefZasJ9Sw76mWka93BokeLy38/YEA6/r/QMH4Gmfjx8)

Answer (score 1):

### C <s>175</s> 169 bytes

```
f(a,b){for(j=a;j<b;j++){n,i=0,x=0;s=0;n=j;while(n!=0){n/=10;i++;}a[i];n=j;while(n!=0){a[i-x-1]=n%10;n/=10;x++;}for(x=0;x<i;x++)s+=(int)pow(a[x],x+1);if(j==s)printf("%d ",s);}}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
void f(int a, int b)
{

  for(int j=a; j<b;j++)
  {
    int n,i=0,x=0;
    int s=0;
    n=j;

   //Convert each number from 'n' to 'm' and store it in an int array 
   while(n)
   {
     n/=10;
     i++;     
   }
   int a[i]; 

   n=j;       
   while(n)
   {
    a[i-x-1]=n%10;
    n/=10;
    x++;     
   }

  //Calculate sum of digits powered with their respective position
  for(x=0;x<i;x++)
   s+=(int)pow(a[x], x+1);

   //Print Desarium
   if(j==s)
    printf("%d ", sum);     
 }

}
```

Can be shortened in some way, but I don't see it at the moment.

@TuukkaX Thanks for saving 6 bytes.

Comment: Both `n!=0` can be changed to `n`.

Comment: You're right, that does make sense!

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 136 bytes

```c
r[]={0,0};f(n){if(n)f(n/10),r[1]=pow((n%10),*r)+r[1]+.5,r[0]++;else*r=1,r[1]=0;}g(m,x){for(;m<=x;m++){f(m);if(m==r[1])printf("%d,",m);}}
```

Header defining pow on TIO because for some reason it didn't auto include pow.  My computer did, so I'm going to roll with that.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#LYzBCsIwEETvfkUoFHabqAniac2XlB4EmxIwaYkVIyHfXhPqYYedfTO7zB@I4ossHRizBsoWxvUdPIusY8tOjwqp4D9QdMhb6AedpJCZDHhMtmqZs5IoQq8GXavg2@q7gLze@OlamBw4p/H5Grug1Z6VlCdwImIycwByNx3JcV4sOKTy22ldg7gE61cDTfsQjSgo583drQdMbAIpLlIisbz9AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 16 bytes

```
&:"@tFYAtn:^s=?@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@69mpeRQ4hbpWJJnFVdsa@/w/78hl6GBAQA)

```
&:        % Input two n, m implicitly. Push array [n n+1 ... m]
"         % For each k in that array
  @       %   Push k
  tFYA    %   Duplicate. Convert to decimal digits
  tn:     %   Duplicate. Push [1 2 ... d], where d is the number of digits
  ^       %   Element-wise power
  s       %   Sum of array
  =       %   Compare with previous copy of k: is it equal?
  ?       %   If so
    @     %     Push k
          %   End, implicit
          % End, implicit
          % Display stack, implicit
```

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, <strike>88</strike> 87 bytes

*Thanks to MattWH for saving a byte (f(x)-48 vs f(x)-'0')*

```
@(n,m,f=@num2str,a=n:m)a(a==cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x){sum((f(x)-48).^(1:nnz(f(x))))},a)))
```

To run:

```
>> f=@(n,m,f=@num2str,a=n:m)a(a==cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x){sum((f(x)-'0').^(1:nnz(f(x))))},a))) 
>> f(0,1000)
ans = 
      1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    89   135   175   518   598
```

### Explanation

```
@(n,m,                                              % Create an anonymous function and pass it n and m as paramteres
    f=@num2str,                                     % Will be using the num2str mehtod twice, set the variable f to the handle to save on bytes
        a=n:m)                                      % Create a vector 'a' and populate it with the numbers n through m
            a(a==                                   % Logically index into a, where the values of a match Disarium numbers
                cell2mat(                           % Convert the cell array returned by arrayfun into a matrix, so we can use it in the logical index
                    arrayfun(@(x){                  % Call the following function on every element of a, using the index named 'x'
                        sum(                        % Sum the matrix that results from the following computation
                            (f(x)-'0')              % Convert the value at index x into a string, then break it into a matrix by subtracting the string '0'.
                                                    % This results in the matrix [1 3 5] for the number 135.
                                .^                  % Compute the element-wise power with the following matrix
                                    (1:nnz(f(x)))   % Create a matrix with the range 1 to the length of the number at index x. This results in the matrix 
                                                    % [1 2 3] for the number 135.
                        )                           % Closes the sum statement
                    },a)                            % Closes the arrayfun statement, passing the matrix a to be operated on
                )
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 115 bytes

```
@for %%d in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 89 135 175 518 598 1306 1676 2427 2646798)do @if %%d geq %1 if %%d leq %2 echo %%d
```

Batch only has 32-bit arithmetic which has no way of comparing the last disarium number, but if you insist on string comparisons, then for 402 bytes:

```
@echo off
for %%d in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 89 135 175 518 598 1306 1676 2427 2646798 12157692622039623539)do call:c %1 %%d&&call:c %%d %2&&echo %%d
exit/b
:c
call:p %1 %2
set r=%s%
call:p %2 %1
:g
if %r:~,1% lss %s:~,1% exit/b0
if %r:~,1% gtr %s:~,1% exit/b1
if %r%==%s% exit/b0
set r=%r:~1%
set s=%s:~1%
goto g
:p
set s=%1
set t=%2
:l
set s=0%s%
set t=%t:~1%
if not "%t%"=="" goto l
```

Answer (score 1):

### Scala, <s>132</s> 129 bytes

```
(% :Int,^ :Int)=>for(i<- %to^)if(((0/:(i+"").zipWithIndex)((z,f)=>{z+BigInt(f._1.toInt-48).pow(f._2+1).intValue}))==i)println(i)
```

---

129 edit: Changing the for loop's variable name from `&` to `i` saved three spaces.

---

### Explanation

For each value in the input range:

- convert it to a string with `+""`
- use `zipWithIndex` to produce a list of tuples containing a char of the digit and its index
- fold the list by returning each char's int value minus 48 (lines up to 0-9) to the power of its list index plus one (to start at ^1)
- if the result matches the input, print it

---

### Comments

Finally got around to learning how `fold` and `zipWithIndex` work. I'm unhappy with the `int` conversions, but I am pleased with the succinctness of `fold` and `zipWithIndex`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
fS=oṠδṁ^ŀd…
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9odXNr//9mUz1v4bmgzrThuYFexYBk4oCm////ODn/NjAw)

## Explanation

```
fS=oṠδṁ^ŀd…
          … inclusive range m to n
f           filter:
  =          is the number equal to
   o     d   the number converted to digits
     δ       zipped with
        ŀ    range 1..length
      ṁ^     raise each digit to those powers
      ṁ      and sum them
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 101 bytes

```c
i;j;a(n,m){char*p;for(i=n;i<m;i++-n||puts(p))for(n=j=0;j++<asprintf(&p,"%d",i);)n+=pow(p[j-1]-48,j);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCoMwEEDRvacQoSXTJKDQRWHMSUoXIUU7wYyDWrpQr97U/u37wfYh5EwY0Ss2Cdbw8tNFsBsnRY6R2oSkteVtk/cyKwH4E7voaoxat36WiXjp1FlMdXpWhgCBtZPxo@QebfOw15uJgHs@tjJ5YgXFWnhVm7KpjwCLPX9DN/h@znZIPw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 72 bytes

```
[ [a,b] [ dup present [ [ digit> ] dip 1 + ^ ] map-index Σ = ] filter ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY6xDsIwDET3foV3SpWuIFgRCwtiiooUUrdEpG5IHAm@h//hl0LaSmzPd7o7d0rz6NPlfDwdNjAovldeUY8BHugJLTiPAYkXyykf0M@8CF0kzWakAAGfEUnn4GxEMnpscYozv503uWJbFAJqUQohkgSpylsDEtro/iNyuk1veA9NBgc1rOCaeVBubajFF3w/sMtCZyznT5qklbVQpR8)

### Explanation:

- `[a,b] [ ... ] filter` Create a range from the inputs (inclusive) and collect numbers for which the quotation returns `t` into a sequence.
- `dup ... =` Create a copy of the input and see if it's equal to the sum of the digits raised to their indices (the `...` part).
- `present` Convert a number to a string.
- `[ ... ] map-index` Apply a quotation to each element of a sequence and collect the results into a sequence of the same length. However, also place the index of the element on top of the stack.
- `[ digit> ] dip` Since the index is on top of the stack, the actual element of the sequence is underneath the index, so we use `dip` to apply a quotation to the object underneath the top of the data stack. `digit>` converts a code point to a digit.
- `1 + ^` Add one to the index (since it's zero-based) and raise the digit to this power.
- `Σ` Sum.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `c`, 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Iædż*S=
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPUklQzMlQTZkJUM1JUJDKlMlM0QmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD01MDAlMEExJmZsYWdzPWVj)

##### Explanation

```python
Iædż*S=  # Implicit input
I        # Inclusive range
 æ       # Filtered by:
  d      #  Split it into digits
   ż     #  Push [1..length]
    *    #  Exponentiation
     S   #  Sum this list
      =  #  Equals the number?
         # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 47 bytes

```arturo
$=>[select&..&'n[0n=∑map digits n'x->x^<=1+]]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?ZWM5jS)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 78 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$b)$a..$b|?{$i=0
$s=0
"$_"|% t*y|%{$s+=,$_*++$i-join'*'|iex}
$s-eq$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcrBDoIgAAbgO0/B3G8aiMNLN9ajMGy4aBYGbtWAZycv3@nb/MeGeLfrKm4@2IpFpbqZYJ49zID5DDOOmPM1wSlJEA8a6Ca3dGe/3CZErgZoxjmceHj36liXnf2W4wr7hi61EHLCQidJL1LWPw)

Alternatively, also for 78 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcndCsIgAAbQe59C5FvzZw676W70KMOFI2PlssEK9dktujycNewuvq5uWfQlRFcxD6muNto7h@0wCdi@x5TPCX4whOtb8A/OMLLc0E1@cpM6pn6USsH/t5VtEdm7t9DuibHUQsgBMz0aejKmfgE)

Answer (score 0):

## Java

```
s->{long i=0,j=0,c,d;for(;j!=s;){String []f=Long.toString(i).split("");for(d=0,c=0;d<f.length;)c+=Math.pow(Long.valueOf(f[d]),++d);if(i==c)j++;}return i;}
```

### Explanation

```
s    - index
i    - iteration variable
j    - matches
c    - sum of each digit^its index
d    - index of digit in i
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3:  131 Bytes

```
n=int(input())
m=int(input())
R=[x for x in range(n,m+1)]
O=[sum(map(int,str(x)))for x in R]
F=[(x**(O.index(x)))for x in O]
L=[x for x in F for w in R if x==w]
print(list(set(L)))
```

After creating this code, it's become apparent that there are a limited number of disariums, so it might be more feasible to check for these explicitly rather than using so much list comprehension which is tough on big inputs to this solution.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/FXAn/0)

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 100 bytes

```
INPUT N,M
FOR I=N TO M
S=0FOR J=1TO LEN(STR$(I))S=S+POW(VAL(STR$(I)[J-1]),J)NEXT
IF S==I THEN?I
NEXT
```